# it seems like i can't open a frame in python

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to open the menu_frame by clicking the login_button but the frame won't come up and there are no error messages showing up. its my first time and im so lost
ive tried to google how to fix this problem but from what ive read, it seems to me that there are no errors or any reason for this code to not function properly. please help :(

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("EL TALLO")
window.geometry("700x490")
window.config(background="#FFF8E5")

#회원가입
def register_frame():
    register_frame = Frame(
        window, 
        bd=2, 
        bg='#FFF8E5',
        relief=SOLID, 
        padx=10, 
        pady=10
        )

    Label(
        register_frame, 
        text="ID입력", 
        bg='#CCCCCC',
        ).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10)

    Label(
        register_frame, 
        text="비밀번호 입력", 
        bg='#CCCCCC',
        ).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10)

    newlyset_id = Entry(
        register_frame 
    )

    newlyset_pw = Entry(
        register_frame, 
        show='*'
    )

    register_btn = Button(
        register_frame, 
        width=15, 
        text='회원가입',
        relief=SOLID,
        cursor='hand2',
        command=register_frame.destroy
    )

    newlyset_id.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=20)
    newlyset_pw.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=10, padx=20)
    register_btn.grid(row=7, column=1, pady=10, padx=20)
    register_frame.pack()
    register_frame.place(x=220, y=150)
    
def new_id(): #new_id에 newlyset_id에 입력한 값을 저장
    new_id = newlyset_id.get()

def new_pw(): #new_pw에 newlyset_pw에 입력한 값을 저장
    new_pw = newlyset_pw.get()

#메뉴화면
def menu_frame():
    menu_frame = Frame(
        window,
        bd=2,
        bg='#FFF8E5',
        relief=SOLID, 
        padx=10, 
        pady=10
        )
    
    label1 = Label(menu_frame, text = "EL TALLO", bg="lightgreen",width=10, height=1, font=(15))
    label1.pack()

    btn1 = Button(menu_frame, text = "play game",  bg="gray",  width=15, height=1)
    btn1.pack()

    btn2 = Button(menu_frame, text = "How to play",  bg="gray", width=15, height=1)
    btn2.pack()

    btn3 = Button(menu_frame, text = "Settings",  bg="gray", width=15, height=1)
    btn3.pack()

    def btncmd():
        print("게임이 종료되었습니다")
    
    btn4 = Button(menu_frame, text = "END GAME", command=btncmd, bg="lightgreen",  width=15, height=1)
    btn4.pack()


    label1.place(x=50, y=50)
    btn1.place(x=50, y=100)
    btn2.place(x=50, y=150)
    btn3.place(x=50, y=200)
    btn4.place(x=50, y=250)
    
#로그인
Label(
    window,
    text="아이디 입력", 
    bg='#CCCCCC',
    ).place(x=230, y=170)

id_tf = Entry(
    window, 
    ).place(x=330, y=170)

def id(): #id에 id_tf에 입력한 값을 저장
    id = id_tf.get()

Label( 
    window, 
    text="비밀번호 입력", 
    bg='#CCCCCC',
    ).place(x=230, y=220)

pw_tf = Entry(
    window, 
    ).place(x=330, y=220)

def pw(): #pw에 pw_tf에 입력한 값을 저장
    pw = pw_tf.get()
    
#회원가입 버튼
registerbutton = Button(
    window,
    width=15,
    text="회원가입",
    bg="#CCCCCC",
    cursor='hand2',
    command=register_frame
    )
registerbutton.place(x=360, y=270)
    
#로그인 버튼
loginbutton = Button(
    window,
    width=15,
    text="로그인",
    bg="#CCCCCC",
    cursor='hand2',
    command=menu_frame
    )
loginbutton.place(x=230, y=270)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pack the menu_frame and the indentation of def btncmd() was wrong.

That is:

```
    btn3 = Button(menu_frame, text = "Settings",  bg="gray", width=15, height=1)
    btn3.pack()
    
    menu_frame.pack()

def btncmd():
    print("게임이 종료되었습니다")
```